# How to insert custom data inside fullcalendar event?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

How do I include custom data inside my fullcalendar object and access it during eventClick?

Example of my code:

```
event: [
  {
    penCount: "2",
    title: "Pens",
    start: date[0]
  },
  {
    penCount: "6",
    title: "Pens",
    start: date[1]
  }
]
```

during eventClick:

```
eventClick: function(info) {
    alert(info.event.penCount);
}
```

The alert shows `undefined`, not the value I expected. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: event is an array...

Comment: @alfasin  but how come i can access the value of 'title' and 'start' using the same code

Comment: Since I didn't see a complete code example which I can review, it's pretty much impossible to answer...

Comment: @alfasin this is a fullcalendar object

Comment: You should be able to construct [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and post it as part of the question. Help us help you!

Comment: @alfasin i've solved my problem and already posted the solution. but thanks for the MCVE info. will make sure to look onto it next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by adding `extendedProps` after the `info.event` object

```
eventClick: function(info) {
    alert(info.event.extendedProps.penCount);
}
```

Comment: For reference for other readers, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing explains how/why this is necessary

Answer (score 0):

Since `event` is an array, you need to put the index of the object you're accessing. 
EX: `info.event[i].penCount`

Comment: i dont think that is the case. since i can get the value of 'title' and 'start' using the same code.

Comment: Its possible you're accessing those alright because they're defined elsewhere in the code but penCount is not. Hard to say as there isn't enough to go on. Did you try the index brackets after all?

Comment: i've solved it and already posted my answer

Comment: @JMCross `event` is not an array in the `eventClick` context, no. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick . Not sure what gave you that idea?